# Android sqlite database access

Tags: android, sqlite

I have made a `sample.sql` database with "SQL Lite Manager".

How can I access this in an Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps to using an existing SQLite data base in an Android project. They are nicely described in [this blog post](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) by Juan-Manuel Fluxà.

Basically, you need to make sure that the data base contains certain tables and column names, then when your program first runs, copy the data base from your assets or resources folder to the standard db location for your app. The latter step is best done by writing a DataBaseHelper class the way that Fluxà describes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your prebuild database file in `/assets` directory in your apk,
2. and on first use copy to `"/data/data/<application_package>/databases/"` directory.

Now use it with SQLite Database Helper class in your android application...

For more info look at this [Article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)